# What does "Find all functions $A \rightarrow B$" mean?

Tags: functions, notation

I keep coming across questions written in this format and I don't understand this notation. An example of a question is: Find all functions $f : \{1,2,3,\ldots\} \rightarrow \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$, such that for all $n = 1, 2, 3,\ldots$ the sum $f(1) + f(2) + ... + f(n)$ is equal to a perfect cube less than or equal to $n^3$.
Another example here: How many functions $g$ can be defined from set $A = \{0, 1,\ldots, 2^n -1, 2^n\}$ to set $B = \{0, \ldots , n\}$ such that $g(2^x) = x$ for all $x \in B$?
I don't need either questions solving but the notation explained.

Comment: A function associates to every element of a  set exactly one element of a set; for example, $f : \{1,2,3...,\}$ $\to\{1,2,3...,\}$ means function $f$ maps the set of natural numbers to the set of natural numbers, in other words, $f$ associates each natural number to a natural number

Comment: In order for your MathJax commands to take effect, you must surround them with `$` signs.  `$2^n$` formats as $2^n$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Ok so in the second example I gave, what is that trying to express, a function that maps all numbers up to some value $2^n$ to values 1 to n?

Comment: ok ty saul, as u can see I already started using the cool dud notation in the previous comment ;)

Comment: @AmeenIzhac:  the second example is asking for functions mapping all numbers (including $0$) up to $2^n$ to values $0$ to $n$

Comment: ok thanks JW i think I understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply specifying the domain and co-domain of the solution function.
Another way of writing "find all functions $f\colon A\to B$ such that $\dots$" is "find all $f\in B^A$ such that $\dots$"

Comment: what is a co domain?

Comment: You may be more familiar with the term "target set"? It is the set into which all of the images of elements of the domain are constrainted to be in,
i.e. if $f$ is a function whose domain is $A$ and whose co-domain is $B$, then $f$ must send each element of $A$ to at most one element of $B$. But note that not all elements in the co-domain need to be reached (it is not the image), so the equation $f(x)=y, x\in A$ may not have a solution for all $y\in B$

Comment: ok thanks I understand now

Answer (score 0):

$f:A\to B$ means $f$ is a function from $A$ into $B$ or onto $B.$

Presumably $\{1,2,3,..\}$ means $\Bbb N,$  the set of positive integers. So the problem reads: Find all functions from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$ such that ... (etc.).

n^3 means $n^3$.

In the 2nd problem $A$ is set of non-negative integers that do not exceed $2^n$ and $B$ is the set of non-negative integers that do not exceed $n.$

Click on the "?" on the top bar (far right), choose Help Center, and click on "How Do I Format Mathematics Here?"

Comment: ok thanks I think I have understood it now